# Managing exceptions in aiohttp using consumer-producer pattern

Tags: python, producer-consumer

I implemented a simple producer-consumer where producer produces links to fetch and several workers consume those URLs and return write data into response queue. Unfortunately, sometimes API can start responding 400-x errors and in that case we need to sleep each for some time. I have implemented it using a queue where I put not only an url, but also time to sleep in case some error happened.

```
class Producer(object):
    def __init__(self, url_queue, total_urls=15):
        self.url_queue = url_queue
        self.total_urls = total_urls

    async def run(self):
        count = 0
        choices = ['blah-%s' % i for i in range(15)]
        while count < self.total_urls:
            await self.url_queue.put(('http://localhost:8080/%s' % choices[count], 0))
            count += 1
            logging.info("Count: %s", count)
            if count % 1000 == 0:
                await asyncio.sleep(1)


class DownloadWorker(object):
    def __init__(self, url_queue: asyncio.Queue,
                 response_queue: asyncio.Queue):
        self.url_queue = url_queue
        self.response_queue = response_queue
        self.count = 0

    async def run(self):
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            while True:
                url, wait = await self.url_queue.get()
                if wait:
                    logging.info("Sleeping for %s ", wait)
                    await asyncio.sleep(wait)

                async with session.get(url) as resp:
                    try:
                        content = await resp.json()
                        await self.response_queue.put(content)
                        logging.info("Content %s", content)
                    except:
                        self.url_queue.put_nowait((url, 3.))
                        logging.exception('Error processing message')
                    finally:
                        self.url_queue.task_done()
```

And here is the code for running producer-worker:

```
  async def worker_pattern(worker_count):
    response_queue = asyncio.Queue()
    url_queue = asyncio.Queue()

    producer = Producer(url_queue)
    producers = [
        asyncio.create_task(producer.run())
    ]

    consumers = []
    for i in range(worker_count):
        worker = DownloadWorker(url_queue, response_queue)
        consumers.append(asyncio.create_task(
            worker.run()
        ))
    await asyncio.gather(*producers)

    await url_queue.join()

    for c in consumers:
        c.cancel()
    return response_queue
```